# combine MYSQL queries without common table expression

Tags: mysql, sql, mysql-workbench

I want to fetch different data from different table.

I write 3 queries but I cant combine the  queries. I tried to combine but not getting actual values

```
    SELECT user.user_id ,email,count(post_id) as posts 
    FROM user
    left join post on user.user_id=post.user_id
    group by user.user_id 
    
    
    SELECT user.user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(members.memberIds)  as datas
    FROM members
    join user on user.user_id =members.user_id
    GROUP BY user.user_id 
    
    
    
    SELECT  user_id,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE 
                 WHEN question.question_name = 'Household'
                 THEN answer.text
                 ELSE NULL 
             END
         ) AS Household,
         GROUP_CONCAT(
             CASE 
                 WHEN question.question_name = 'Dependents' 
                 THEN answer.text
                 ELSE NULL 
             END
         ) AS Dependents
      
    FROM user_answers
    inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
    inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
    GROUP BY user_id
```

here I am getting 3 results.

[image: 3data]

I want a result as

[image: required]

how can I get this ?

I tried to join my 1st query and second query at that time I am getting incorrect value in column'datas'

how can I go this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using your SQL, I would create the following query:

```
SELECT 
user.user_id,
user.email,
COUNT(post.post_id) as posts,
a.datas,
b.Household,
b.Dependents 
FROM user
left join post on user.user_id=post.user_id

-- left join first query as subquery
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT user.user_id,GROUP_CONCAT(members.memberIds)  as datas
FROM members
join user on user.user_id =members.user_id
GROUP BY user.user_id 
) AS a
ON a.user_id = user.user_id

-- left join second query as subquery
LEFT JOIN (
SELECT  user_id,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Household'
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Household,
     GROUP_CONCAT(
         CASE 
             WHEN question.question_name = 'Dependents' 
             THEN answer.text
             ELSE NULL 
         END
     ) AS Dependents
  
FROM user_answers
inner join answer on user_answers.answer_id=answer.answer_id
inner join question on answer.question_id=question.question_id
GROUP BY user_id
) AS c
ON c.user_id = user.user_id

group by user.user_id
```

The LEFT JOIN is because there might be users without datas and/or answers.

Now there are other ways of doing this, but if you're current queries give the required result, there's nothing wrong with subqueries.